# how to fix yum install php-mysqli error

Tags: php, centos, installation, yum

I installed php-msqli on Centos 6.5, but it shows this error:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read in the [help] how to effectively ask questions. You need to include error messages in your question, same as the code. It's often difficult to read what's in images and, if they're not show in the question, some people can't/won't use an outside link.

Comment: Where did you install it from? Looks like that repo has missing deps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed!

For someone need: use this command

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-mysqli
```

Comment: better to permanently enable the "remi-php56" repo, as explained by the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/